# Store says I don't have enough space, but I do

Tags: store, storage

I'm trying to download a Game called Dungeon Hunter 4, it takes around 700mb, I have more than 1,5Gb free and still I cant download the Game, it says i must clear space. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Packages are first downloaded, and then unpacked/installed, and it is that download size that is shown in the store. Because it has to download it and then install, you typically need at least twice the size of the package free to install it (although the size of the download package would be freed after installation)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understand now! But I have 1,80Gb and the Game is 726mb and I cant download it still

Comment: The file that is being downloaded is compressed heavily so maybe you need three or four times the size that is shown in the store.?